# mybinder works OK with a branch but not with another

Tags: r, mybinder

I may be missing something obvious here, but I'm encountering a very weird behaviour. If I launch `mybinder` on the `main` branch of my repo (https://github.com/StatisticsHealthEconomics/stat0019_binder/tree/main), all works fine. However, if I use a different branch (which, incidentally does have the **exact** same `Dockerfile` and `apt.txt`), `mybinder` fails to launch complaining that
`E: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is not signed.`
(this happens for a few repos, actually).

I'm not sure why this is, because, like I said, the config files are identical. Also, the first time I launched `mybinder` after creating the new branch, it did work, but after that it stopped...

Anyone can help me make sense of this? Apologies if I'm missing something obvious, like I said...

Thanks!
Gianluca

Comment: Currently, [there](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/my-binder-repo-randomly-stopped-working/14525/2?u=fomightez) is a discussion (and others I don't have space to paste) how spurious issues are being reported as builds are tried, especially with apt.  Sort of an aside, this type of question would best be posted in the 'Binder' help category over at [the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org) as it involves more discussion usually to optimize what you can do. Stackoverflow discourages such discussions. Also, the 'pulse' of MyBinder can better be assessed there.

Comment: The other recent discussions I wanted to include are [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/docker-build-failed-on-installing-ffmpeg-using-a-apt-txt-config-file/14515/4?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/binder-launch-fails-with-oserror-errno-28-no-space-left-on-device/14530/7?u=fomightez). Usually as you found it just gets resolved if you try later. **You'd have to include the name of the branch** (you have more than one aside from main) **for me to test and see if I can offer a better launch experience for you.**

Comment: Thank you, @Wayne. The relevant branch is `bmhe`. I have seen some discussion suggesting that the problem may be with `mybinder.org` --- in fact, if I try running from `https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/` it works...

Comment: Everything should be working [from all locations in the MyBinder federation now](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/binder-launch-fails-with-oserror-errno-28-no-space-left-on-device/14530/17?u=fomightez) and so for the sake of traffic management in the service, please use the normal launch URLs that begin with `http://mybinder.org/v2/ ...` again.